# det-1 is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I'm interesting about $V(det-1) \subset \mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ with the determinant seen as a polynomial. I know that $det$ is irreducible. But I want to show that $det-1$ is irreducible. In a paper, it says that if $det-1=fg$ is a non trivial factorization so the top homogeneous components of $f$ and $g$ gives a non  trivial factorization for $det$. I don't understand why.

Cordialy,
doeup

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\det$ is a homogeneous polynomial in $n$ variables of the same degree. Then $\det-1$ has two homogeneous components, one in homogeneous degree $n$ and one in homogeneous degree $0$. If $f,g$ are any two polynomials and $\det-1=fg$, the homogeneous components of $fg$ of degree $n$ must be $\det$, the $0$th one must be $-1$, and all others should vanish.