# Special linear group is an irreducible algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an infinite field (possibly algebraically closed).

I'm trying to prove that the set of $n\times n$ matrices with entries on $k$ and determinant $1$, $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$, is an affine variety (by affine variety I will refer to an irreducible algebraic set of $\mathbb{A}_k^{n^2}$). I've been instructed to prove it using these facts:

1. Morphisms between quasi-affine varieties are continuous (which respect to the Zariski topologies).
2. Continuity preserves irreducibility (that is, a continuous function between irreducible topological spaces has irreducible image).
3. Open sets of an irreducible topological space are also irreducible.

I've been given also the hint to look for a morphism between $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ (the general linear group of degree $n$ over $k$) and $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$.

I already know that $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ is a quasi-affine variety (i.e., an open set of an affine variety) and that $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ is an algebraic set. It remains for me to see that $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ is irreducible. By the third previous fact, $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)=\operatorname{M}_n(k)\setminus\det^{-1}(0)$ is an irreducible topological space (for $\operatorname{M}_n(k)\cong\mathbb{A}_k^{n^2}$, the set of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $k$, is irreducible since $k$ is infinite). Thus, by the second previous fact, to give a morphism $\phi:\operatorname{GL}_n(k)\to\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ whose image coincides with $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ suffices for the proof. However, I can only come up with this definition for the morphism: $\phi(A)=\frac{A^n}{\det A}$ (recall that $\det$ is homogeneous of degree $n$). $\phi$ is indeed a quasi-affine varieties morphism and by construction $\operatorname{Im}\phi\subset\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$. Nevertheless, proving the reverse inclusion would require to prove that the $n$-th root for a matrix of $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ always exists. For what I've been looking up on the internet and MSE, this may be non-trivial or even not true in general. From here, I don't see how to continue.

*Edit:* Thanks to KReiser's comments I've found a proof for the irreducibility of $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$ which passes through proving that $\det X-1$ is irreducible (where $X=(x_{ij})$ is an $n\times n$ matrix on the indeterminates $x_{ij}$). Problem is this proof is purely algebraic, and I'm still interested on finding a proof which uses the technique stated above: to look for a quasi-affine varieties morphism $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)\to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ with image equal to $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$. Still, I have no clue about how to come up with the morphism.

Any help on the topic will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a strange approach to the problem. Why not just use the fact that $SL_n(k)$ is the matrices of determinant one? This immediately gives $SL_n(k)=V(\det-1)\subset\Bbb A^{n^2}$.

Comment: You mean proving that $\det-1$ is irreducible?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If $fg=\det-1$, then the top-degree components of $f$ and $g$ must have product $\det$ - can you finish from here?

Comment: Another approach is to show that there are no closed subgroups of finite index in $SL_n(k)$ (you might have seen that irreducible components of an algebraic group are the cosets of the identity component, which have finite index - if you haven't seen this, intuitively the idea is that the group as an affine variety has a canonical decomposition into (finitely many) irreducible components).

Comment: @KReiser I've found a proof that builds upon your hint, thanks! The problem is that it's purely algebraic, and I'm still interested in a proof which uses the technique stated on my question: to look for a quasi-affine varieties morphism $\operatorname{GL}_n(k) \to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ with image equal to $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$. Still, I have no clue about how to come up with the morphism.

Comment: Well, how about dividing all entries in a chosen row or column by the determinant? This guarantees determinant one and is surjective because it leaves everything in $SL_n$ invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kreiser comments give the answer: one could just simply prove that $\det -1$ is irreducible (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2958118/394668) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147085/394668)). The other way, following the original path, is to consider the morphism $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)\to \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ which takes each matrix $A\in \operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ and maps it to a matrix equal to $A$ except for the first row, which is equal to that of $A$ divided by the determinant of $A$. It's straighforward to check that the image of this morphism is indeed $\operatorname{SL}_n(k)$.